# Insert Image in Excel column VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code, which inserts image in Excel sheet in the right cell wherever I type image name. But I want it to work only in A:B Ranges:
Type Name in cells of column A and it will insert image in the next cell - column B.
Here is my code which I want to modify:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range
    Dim myPath As String

    myPath = "P:\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Dir(myPath & "*" & c.Text & "*") = "" Then
            InsertPicture myPath & Dir(myPath & "*" & c.Text & "*"), c.offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'

Sub InsertPicture(thePath As String, theRange As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(thePath)

        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = theRange.Width
            .Height = theRange.Height
        End With

        .Left = theRange.Left
        .Top = theRange.Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True

    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make a check on the `Target.Address` (the `Target` being the range modified). 
I would also make a count of the `Target` to make sure it's only one `Range`:

```
If (Target.Count > 1) Or (Split(Target.Address,"$")(1) <> "A") Then Exit Sub
```

Explanation: the test above should be done in the beginning of the action macro `Worksheet_Change` and does the following:

1. `Target.Count` returns the number of cells in the `Target` (i.e. the number of cells that have changed). Since I guess you want the user to type only one name of the image at a time, you check for the `Target.Count` and if it's larger than 1 you `Exit Sub`
2. The second check is on the column letter. The variable `Target.Address` returns the address like this (for example): `$A$15`. You `Split` this string by the delimiter `$`, so the function `Split(Target.Address,"$")` will return an array like this: `("","A","15")`. You get the second element of it `(1)` and you test it against the value "A". If it's not `"A"` (i.e. if the user modified a cell that is not in the column `A`), then you `Exit Sub` and you don't attach any image.

Comment: I made changes and it works now. Thank you very much for detailed explanation!

Comment: Hi all. The code works excellent, but now I have another issue, I couldn't solve( When I send the file to external users, they don't see the images. Is there any way to modify the code so as  after inserting it doesn't keep the link, because I guess it because of the links, that people not connecting my server are not able to see the images in the file.